# Outlook cannot synchronize after joining organization

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-teams

I recently joined a Microsoft Teams organization using my personal (Microsoft 365) email address, and since then the Outlook app (Version 2103 Build 13901.20400) on my Windows machine has not been able to synchronize mail or calendar.

I get the following event:

> The Exchange web service request GetAppManifest failed. The error code is 0.
> HTTP response code: 401
>
> Additional Error Message:
> An unknown internal error occurred. The error code is 80004005

There are no problems when going via outlook.live.com or when using the Outlook app on my iPhone.

I've tried adding a new Outlook profile, but I only get a very generic error message when I try to connect it to my account.

I've also tried leaving the organization. That has only given me a new event in the log:

> The Exchange web service request GetAppManifest failed. The error code is 4294967295.
> HTTP response code: 200
>
> Additional Error Message:
> User must have a mailbox for name resolution operations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Outlook access to your email account has been denied as this document: [The HTTP status code in IIS 7.0 and later versions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code) says.

[image]
[image]

Have you ever tried to remove your Outlook-related registry keys to reset Outlook autodiscover settings like below?

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0

Rename Outlook as Outlook1

Restart Outlook to test

[image]

Comment: Now I have. It forces me to add an account, and when I do that I get the same generic error message as when I tried creating a new profile.

Comment: Maybe you could try Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer tool to check your connection from your desktop client to your mail server. https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365Ola/input